# WinError 32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, windows, file-handling

```
import os
def delt(p):
    a=open("D:\\Parthiv\\Py\\1.name.txt",'r')
    c=a.readlines()
    c.pop(p)
    a.close()
    os.remove("D:\\Parthiv\\Py\\1.name.txt")
    b=open("D:\\Parthiv\\Py\\temp.txt",'w')
    for i in range(0,len(c)):
        f=c[i]
        b.write(f)
    b.close()
    os.rename("D:\\Parthiv\\Py\\temp.txt","D:\\Parthiv\\Py\\1.name.txt")
delt(0)
```

With this code, I want to define a function which deletes a particular line from any file, without using any external libraries. But it raises the following error:

```
----> 7     os.remove("D:\\Parthiv\\Py\\1.name.txt")
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'D:\\Parthiv\\Py\\1.name.txt'
```

How come this error when I have already closed the file with `a.close()`?

Comment: You're code works for me (on Windows 7). Do you have the `D:\\Parthiv\\Py\\1.name.txt` file open in any other application, like a text editor or your IDE?